# Nginx Rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

My index works fine, other pages don't work and show me error 500, my output log is

```
2016/11/23 17:26:47 [error] 51445#0: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: projetofinal.dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "projetofinal.dev", referrer: "http://projetofinal.dev/categoria/noticias"
```

I tried others solutions in forum but i did not suceed

Folder structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K85n7.png

My Server Block

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   projetofinal.dev;
    root          /var/www/cursos/ws_php/modulos/12-projeto-final;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/?url=$1;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/projetofinal.access.log main;
    error_log   /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/projetofinal.error.log;

    # PHP-FPM SUPPORT
    include     /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
}
```

Comment: What's the contents of /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm ?

Comment: @Uthr this `location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files                   $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass                127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index               index.php;
    fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include                     fastcgi_params;
}`

Comment: What happens if you replace `/index.php/?` with `/index.php?`?

Comment: @Uthr logs shows nothing, no error occurs in browser but don't work, don't open page, still on home

Comment: Why are you using a back reference when you're not storing anything from a regex? (`url=$1`)

Comment: @KeenanLawrence check how i mount the url http://pastebin.com/0fH5bHyk

Comment: @KeenanLawrence and my config file http://pastebin.com/EQTYCYe6

Comment: i don't found solution yet :/